# When using Hyperledger Fabric with Kafka consensus, is persistent storage required for kafka and zookeeper nodes?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using a hyperledger fabric 1.1 setup. All the services are containerized within a docker swarm. I'm trying to plan for contingency in case some of the nodes go down. Is there a need to map any volumes to my Kafka or Zookeeper containers for such cases, or is making /var/hyperledger/production persistent on orderer and peer containers enough to reestablish the chain in case of downtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to persist the storage for the Kafka and Zookeeper nodes.

For Kafka, you can set the **KAFKA_LOG_DIRS** env variable and then make sure you attach an external volume to that directory.

For Zookeeper, the default data directory is **/data** so just attach an external volume to that directory